# SPA unable to locate my AngularJS app.js file when uploaded on server. Works locally

Tags: angularjs

I have checked and it seems to be keyed in correctly:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="evPotDataCtrl">
```

When I run my SPA locally it works fine.  However, upload it to my web-server and it fails to locate the file.  I have also set up a bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AngularCustom").IncludeDirectory
                    ("~/app", "*.js", true));
```

The file is located in a folder called app, which is located in the root directory.  I have checked the server folder and all the files have successfully uploaded and I have also checked the permissions on the folder.

I have sent a request to the server administrator, however if I have missed something out, I would appreciate if one of you could tell me.  Thank you.

Comment: Where is your index.html uploaded? And does it have the same relative position to the app.js as locally? Also are the rights to the app.js set correctly on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use bundles in published webSite (without debug mode) it combine all the files into one.

Try to had `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and debug localy, you may have an error in this process.

Comment: Thank you for this.  There was a minor bug in one of the controllers, that was causing the app.js not to work properly.